# Анонимная функция выводит ссылку на себя

Tags: python

Пытаюсь заставить работать анонимную функцию, но вместо этого она выводит ссылку на себя:

Сам код:

```
import random
deff=print(lambda a, aa: print('вы угадали') if a==aa else print(f'вы не угадали, было загадано {aa}'))
deff(int(input('введите')), random.randint(1, 5))
```

То, что выходит:

> <function  at 0x7b4bde21f0>

Comment: а зачем вы выводите ее на печать (первый print)?

Answer (score 1):

Уже решил проблему , просто убрал print()